# Getting to a black screen while setting up grouped table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a nib file that I have put inside of this nib a UITableView (grouped), sets the delegate and datasource of the table view to the file's owner, and created an outlet reference to this table view in the table view controller (files owner).

[image]

in the TargetsTableViewController i'v just set it up to see something, without some collection, just manually said I want 1 section and 5 rows:

```
#import "TargetsTableViewController.h"

@interface TargetsTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation TargetsTableViewController

- (id)init {

    self = [super initWithNibName:@"TargetsTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIBarButtonItem *closeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Close" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(close)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = closeButton;
}

-(void)close {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TargetsTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!cell)
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TargetsTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }


    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

and I have also a basic nib for a cell.

but when I run it I get this black screen:

[image]

does anyone know why is this?

thanks

Comment: Is this a start view controller? Probably you forgot set a root view controller in app delegate?

Answer (score 0):

try set tableview's frame or use some auto layout. You can use tableviewcell without register it. You may seeing the backgroundColor of UIWindow, and you got nothing on view to see, or in another word, a tableview with frame of CGRectZero.